# How to compute the infinite sum given by a (fourier) series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I hope I haven't overseen a thread to this question.

I really struggle with a part of an exercise we have to solve in my Analysis Lecture.

We have a Fourier Series given as:

$$\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sin(kx)$$

And we do have the beginning of a sum, that we are asked to calculate, given as:

$$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}+...$$

So we looked for a value of $x$ and a prefactor that are fullfilling the sum. We ended up with this:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{3} \right)$$

Now I come to the **Main Question**:

**How can I compute an infinite sum?** We have done a computation for $\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k²} = \frac{\pi}{6}$ but I couldn't really understand the way our lecturer computed it. I guess the way to solve the sum is very similar to the series we computed in the lecture, though.

So I hope I can get some help here on this stackexchange. I only saw threads that asked for validation of their results, but sadly no further explanation.

**Side questions:**

- Is the reult of a infinite series its limit?
- Is the fourier series we made up correct to describe the sum?

Thanks in advance for everyone who takes the time to help.

Comment: First of all thank you. I still can't grasp the concept completely, though. What is your end value of the sum. And could I actually say that my $f(x)$ is the second series I posted? The thing I can't understand is how I could possibly compute a infinite series

Comment: How can you compute the infinite sum? Your series is equivalent to some function $f(x)$ i.e $$f(x) \sim \sum_{k \ge 0} a_{k} \cos \left(\frac{k \pi x}{L} \right) + b_{k} \sin \left(\frac{k \pi x}{L} \right)$$ Now evaluate the LHS and RHS at a specific value of $x$ (a value of $x$ that is in the domain of your Fourier series _and_ isn't a discontinuous point) that gives the required series. For example, the series you are trying to find is equivalent to $f(\pi / 3)/\sqrt{3}$ i.e $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} f \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right) = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} + \dots$$

Comment: And the result of $f(\frac{\pi}{3})$ is the limit of the series?

Comment: The reason why you can compute the sum of the infinite series is because, by Dirichlets theorem, the Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$ at every continuous point $x$ in the domain of $f$, and converges to the average of the left and right side values at a discontinuous point.

Comment: No, the result $f(\pi / 3)$ is $\sqrt{3}$ times the value of the series you want to know, provided $\pi / 3$ is a continuous point.

Comment: Ahh Alright. I think I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask what specific function your Fourier series converges to?

Comment: This series looks like it converges to the identity on $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: Converges to the sawtoothfunction $y = -2 \pi k + x$

Comment: @humanStampedist yes you are correct

Comment: @MLK If the Fourier series is of the function $f(x) = x$, then the value of your sum will equal $\pi / 3 \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Yes I just realized, which turned my question into a very silly thing :D Thank you though for taking the time :)